# Is it possible to convert an EXE file back to a Bat

Tags: batch-file, exe

A few years ago I made a batch text based RPG and I wanted to go back to it, but I found the EXE of the game but I was wondering if it's possible to revert it back into bat format?

edit: Sorry for the lack of information, A few years ago I used a bat to EXE converter and I'm wondering if I can convert the EXE back into bat format to work on the game again, the EXE was also found on an old cloud of mine so that is the only file present

Comment: Are you saying you created a batch file to run a game, and you still have the EXE of the game, but you've lost the batch file??

Comment: I doubt it is possible. Am I understanding correctly that you used some special tool to convert BAT file to EXE? What is it?

Comment: Well, without any details I guess no one is able to provide specific help. Anyway, a lot of, not to say most, BAT-to-EXE converters just create a self-extracting archive, which, when being executed, extract the batch file into some temporary directory, runs it and probably removes it finally...

Comment: Try using a resource viewer/hacker to see if the batch file is inside the executable as a resource.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'll try this, I'm not sure what tool I'm meant to use but I'll have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is possible... the truth is most Batch to EXE converters don't actually convert your code, but instead wrap them in an exe file.. so when you run your exe what its actually doing is placing a copy of your original batch file into your temporary directory and running it from there...

what you need to do is open your user file.. thats the directory that holds your documents and pictures and whatnot.. and at the end of your user directory in the address bar, type..
\AppData\Local\Temp

or %temp% in your command line

Comment: You can also type `%TEMP%` directly into the directory bar. It depends on which bat-to-exe converter got used, but it will most likely be in one of the folders that have ".tmp" at the end of the name.

Comment: @yuvalchen This was a few years ago and I found the EXE in an old cloud storage, There is nothing in my Temp folder

Comment: @yuvalchen After looking into it more, I figured out what you meant, Thanks for the answer!